# Full-width header and footer consisting of three images, one of them of variable width

Tags: css, background-image

I am trying to get a header and footer consisting of three sub-elements to work. The header and footer are purely cosmetical and not intended for navigation and are supposed to span the full width of the page. For both the header and footer I've got three images each to work with, one fixed-width unique image for each side and a 1px image that is supposed to fill the space inbetween those.

[image: Concept image]

The HTML of the header is pretty basic:

```
<div id="header-container">
    <div id="header-left">
    </div>
    <div id="header-mid">
    </div>
    <div id="header-right">
    </div>
</div>
```

I've got quite close with absolute positioning, but then the header is fixed and will always stay on top, which is definitely unintended behaviour (#header-mid is unnecessary here):

```
div#header-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background: url(images/header-spacer.png) repeat-x;
}

div#header-left {
    position: absolute;
    width: 600px;
    height: 70px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url(images/header-left.png);
}

div#header-mid {
    display: none;
}

div#header-right {
    position: absolute;
    width: 600px;
    height: 70px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: url(images/header-right.png);
}
```

[JSFiddle example with images](http://jsfiddle.net/5j6UD/) (make sure your Result-window is wider than 1200px)

Using relative positioning I was not able to get the background-images to show and using HTML to show the images won't work with the header-mid.

I've found an incredibly lot of guides on full-width headers/footers on the web, but none that discussed explicitly this kind of combination.

Thanks to [Soheil Gh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2324697/soheil-gh) for answering the question for the header, however that method does not apply to the footer. [Here is an additional JSFiddle including the footer](http://jsfiddle.net/5j6UD/2/).

Comment: header container is absolute . its children dont need to absolute.

Comment: what is problem with footer?

Comment: The footer is further down the page, one needs to scroll to reach it. So setting `bottom: 0`does not work. This is not in the fiddle, but it would be apparent if one inserts a lot of text between header and footer there.

Comment: set `bottom:0` with `position:absolute` only show footer when you reach end of page but   `bottom:0` with `position:fixed` show the footer always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
div#header-container {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 85px;
background: url(images/header-spacer.png) repeat-x;
}

div#header-left {

width: 640px;
height: 85px;
float:left;
background: url(images/header-left.png);
}

div#header-mid {
float:left;
/*insert background image*/
}

div#header-right {

width: 640px;
height: 85px;
 float:right;
background: url(images/header-right.png);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works like a charm. Apparently, the only thing I missed when trying to use relative positioning is to leave the middle element floating to the left.

Comment: I know I've just been asking for a solution for a header, but how would I handle a footer like this? setting `bottom: 0` is not an option, as one would need to scroll to reach the footer.

Comment: You usually define a container div with relative positioning. Then, the elements inside, if defined with absolute positioning, will be displayed absolutely INSIDE the container div.